# Using SQL code with excel power pivot

Tags: sql, powerpivot

I'm using SQL code (which I do not know, I just tried to copy from a sample tutorial) to merge documents to use in Excel PowerPivot. I have an excel file called 2014, and another file called 2015. This was the syntax shown in the example to merge the two, but it keeps telling me columns not identified. How can I fix this?

```
SELECT ['2015$'].*  FROM ['2015$']
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM 'C:\Alex\2014.xlsx'.['2014$'];
```

Comment: For `Union All` to work both tables must have same number of columns, same type and at least the first table has to have all it's columns named

Comment: Is the syntax ok? They have the same number of columns and the first table does have it's columns named= Column 1 through Column 6 in excel. Thanks.

Comment: better if you share more information. Like table structure of your first table and column details of the excel file you are referring to.